# How to pass params with arrow function in ReactJS hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, arrow-functions

I am new to `ReactJS`, I am confused how to pass params with arrow functions, I tried to use `.bind()` to bind the value so i can use it in the `function` but it didn't work, and passing it like a normal function didn't work as well.

**My Code**

```
const getCheckById = (checkID) =>{
    console.log(checkID)
}

<div className=''>
    {
        // allChecks is an array of objects
        allChecks.map((el,index) => {
        return <div key ={index}>
                <span onClick={getCheckById(el.checkID)}>+</span>
            </div>
        })
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const getCheckById = (checkID) =>{
    console.log(checkID)
}


<div className=''>
    {
        // allChecks is an array of objects
        allChecks.map((el,index) => {
        return <div key ={index}>
                <span onClick={() => getCheckById(el.checkID)}>+</span>
            </div>
        })
    }
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, does this works with normal functions as well? `function getCheckById (checkID){
    console.log(checkID)
}`

Comment: The problem with your code is not the function but the fat that you were calling it. When you do this: `<span onClick={getCheckById(el.checkID)}>+</span>`, you where calling the function immediately. When I do this: `<span onClick={() => getCheckById(el.checkID)}>+</span>`, I am wrapping the function call in an arrow function.